# C++ custom vector implementation – subscript of pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, containers, compiler-warnings

As a part of a homework targeted on practicing deep/shallow copy concept I tried to implement very basic templated vector class (as well as simplistic string) to make further coding easier.

I implemented data as array of pointers, however I encountered following warning with my destructor: *Deleting pointer to incomplete type '*<insert type for which class was instantiated>*' may cause undefined behavior*.

And also error *Subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'myString[]'* with copy constructor (which I believe is result of the same problematic approach as with destructor).

I wrote destructor as simple `delete [] m_data` hoping that this is the right way to ensure that respective destructors of objects stored gets called.

Therefore I would like to ask

1. whether there is any *more proper* way of doing this,
2. whether my approach to this class is somehow fundamentally flawed with respect to failing copy constructor.

```cpp
template <typename T>
myVector<T>::myVector ( const myVector<T> & x ) : m_size(x.m_size), m_capacity(x.m_capacity), m_data( allocate(x.m_capacity) ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < x . m_size; ++ i )
        m_data[i] = x . m_data[i];
}
```

```cpp
template <typename T>
class myVector {
    static const size_t INIT_CAPACITY = 5;
    static const unsigned GROW_FACTOR = 2;

    size_t  m_size;
    size_t  m_capacity;
    T ( * m_data )[];

    template <typename U>
    friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & os, const myVector<U> & );

    static T (* allocate( size_t size )) [] {
        return (T (*)[])malloc(sizeof(T) * size );;
    }

    static T (* reallocate( T (* data)[], size_t size )) [] {
        return (T (*)[]) realloc( data, sizeof(T) * size );
    }

    void print( std::ostream & os ) const;

public:
                   myVector    ();
                   myVector    ( const myVector<T> & );
                  ~myVector    ();
    void           push_back   ( const T & );
    T &            operator[]  ( size_t idx );
    const T &      operator[]  ( size_t idx ) const;
    myVector<T> &  operator=   ( const myVector<T> & );
    T *            begin       ();
    T *            end         ();
    size_t         size        () const;
    void           clear       ();
};
```

Comment: It may be late but doesn't `T ( * m_data )[];` declare a pointer to an array instead of an array of pointers? And then I wouldn't delete[] memory which I malloc()ed. On the plus side I like your source code layout (I'm not being sarcastic).

Comment: Oh, additionally, the errors and warnings are caused by the declaration of a vector containing a type and that type has been declared but not defined.  Make sure the type is completely defined before declaring a vector that holds that type.  It is possible to write the vector so that this isn't necessary, but you have to be really careful how you implement the vector members.  Don't bother for a mere learning exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "I impemented data as array of pointers" ...
>
> "destructor as simple `delete [] m_data`" ...
>
> `(T (*)[])malloc(sizeof(T) * size );`
>
> `realloc`...

*Everything* is wrong.

*One*, you cannot use `realloc` when dealing with unknown C++ objects at all. You will get undefined behaviour and actual memory corruption.

*Two*, you cannot mix `malloc` and `delete` (or `delete[]`). Use `new[]` with `delete[]`, `new` with `delete`, and `malloc` with `free` (except you should not use `malloc`).

*Three*, you are claiming to use an array of pointers, but you are declaring a pointer-to-array; then you are allocating an array of T, and casting it to the pointer-to-array type.

I think it's enough for now. Scrap the code in its entirety and start over. The correct, no-nonsense way is as follows:

```
T* data; // that's your artray data
data = new T[size];  // allocation
delete [] data; // destruction
```

No casts of any kind **ever**. No pointers other than `data`. Resize by manually calling `new[]`, copy old data in a loop with the assignment operator, then `delete[]` old data. There are *more proper* ways but they are considerably more complicated. Try mastering the basics first.

Comment: I think allocating an array of `T` and then casting to the pointer-to-array type _might_ be safe, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Also, the last paragraph might be wrong, depending on if he wants to overallocate like `std::vector` does.  The comments imply that he does indeed want to overallocate.

Comment: I think the OP was trying to use _pointers_ to T, so that a realloc would be entirely fine (well, as fine as realloc can be, but then what will new do on many systems?).

Comment: But of course it's not clear who owns the pointers etc., e.g. when assigning to elements and thus overwriting pointers which may be the only object handle left. Smart pointers could be a solution, but I have no experience with e.g. unique_ptr. Anybody?

Comment: @MooingDuck if the OP wants to (over)allocate uninitialized memory, and construct objects in it as needed, that's the "considerably more complicated" part. He needs uninitialized properly aligned memory, placement `new`, explicit destructor calls and maybe more weird stuff. Let's start with just allocating a bunch of default-initialized `T`s, OK?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I'm at a loss as to why you think it's not clear who owns the pointers.  Clearly the vector would own the pointers.  There would also only be one pointer to each element, so theres no "overwriting the only object handle left".  I don't understand your confusion or train of thought at all...

Comment: @MooingDuck: I think the OP wants to use the vector like this: `v[0] = new myElaborateClass`, or perhaps `v[0] = &myClassWithoutAssignment;`. Who owns the pointers? What happens if myClassWithoutAssignment goes out of scope? of course it's then funny that operator[] returns a T& but that's easily coded by returning *m_data[i].

Comment: @PeterSchneider *If* pointers are just an implementation detail of the custom vector, then the vector should be owning them. This variation is somewhat more complicated exception safety wise. Smart pointers are of course OK, but then so is `std::vector`; if one needs to do everything from scratch it's suddenly not that attractive any more.

Comment: @n.m. Obviously this is an exercise, like copying an old scandinavian master ;-). That _is_ attractive to some, and certainly _instru_ ctive.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: That's a possibility I had not considered, but I don't see anything in his code or comments that even remotely implies that that's what he wants to do (as you noted by the `operator[]`)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, he said "I impemented [sic] data as array of pointers", didn't he? And he was just one misplaced pair of brackets short of actually doing that ;-).

Comment: @n.m. I used `reallocate()` approach with idea that this implementation would be instantiated with simple classes only. However this assumption, which was supposed to accelerate development of this support class, in fact is hampering my ability to finish before deadline. Now I am going to rewrite vector class according to your suggestion.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, directly assigning pointers to elements wouldn't work with the operator[] he provides... so the assignment would still be `v[0] = x`, not `&x` (of course he can still store the address of x, but that's pretty opaque). Probably just a big confusion. I'm going to bed, gn.